# I need only hours, minutes and seconds for countdown

Tags: javascript, countdown

I need only hours, minutes and seconds for countdown, I search for others js
in google but didn't found what i m looking for.

I don't need days.

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("March 15, 2019 22:25:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Just remove the `days + "d " + ` bit?  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: Its just showed only hours but instead of showing hours for 3 days for eg. 59 hours,
Its showing 10 hrs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("March 15, 2019 22:25:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();
    
  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
    
  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor(((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)) + days * 24);
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    
  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
    
  // If the count down is over, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Updated the code snippet.

> var hours = Math.floor(((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 *
>   60 * 60)) + days * 24);
>   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + "h "   + minutes +
>   "m " + seconds + "s ";

Comment: You need to just add the hours for the calculated days i.e. if you have 2 days then you need to add 48 i.e. 24*2 hours.

Comment: My Pleasure.  
@BimalPariyar: If you got the expected answer. can you please mark it "As A correct Answer".?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below Code: http://covelign.com/3bNa

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2021 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  var hrs = (days*24)+hours; 

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hrs + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text 
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```